# No option to select Ubuntu at Boot Menu after installing Ubuntu 13.04 alongside Windows 8

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows-8

I purchased a Sony Vaio laptop which has Windows 8 pre-installed. I have a project which requires a Unix operating system, so I am trying to install Ubuntu 13.04 alongside Window 8.

I followed the steps from:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows

I am not able to get past the last step (#7).

My system is not showing the option in the Boot Menu to choose Ubuntu.

What do I need to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Answer (score 2):

When I look at [the page you linked to](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows), I noticed this

> Windows installer is not compatible with Windows 8 or UEFI firmware, and is not available for Ubuntu 13.04.

I think this applies your situation.

Please try to install the Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit version in dual boot instead of using the Windows installer.

You might find [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) about installation with EFI helpful.